# free() collecting garbage value in c code and code doesn't work even when setting the pointer to NULL after freeing

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, free

When I try to call free() function to free the memory, it isn't working properly. Here is my code:

```
unsigned char *indata;
unsigned char *outdata;

int file_func(const char *filename) {
//some other variables

for(i=0;i < no_of_files;i++) {
indata = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));
outdata = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));

//counts the number of characters from filename
numCharacters = readfile(filename, indata); 

/* perform some operation on indata and get outdata(size is same as indata)*/

writefile(filename, outdata);   //writes outdata to filename

    free(indata);
    free(outdata);
    }
}
```

The above code does not work properly because free() is storing some random garbage value at indata & outdata(as they become dangling pointers). So I tried setting the pointers to null after freeing since I'm reusing the same pointers as:

```
    free(indata);
    indata = NULL;
    free(outdata);
    outdata = NULL;
```

Even then my code gets crashed as :

double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000025aa240 ***

How can I overcome this problem or is there any other alternative to use dynamic sized pointers in a loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only allocating 1 byte (`sizeof(unsigned char)`) for each of those variables. Either that's a mistake and you wanted to allocate `sizeof(unsigned char) * some_number` where `some_number` is dynamic, or you could just allocate on the stack:

```
unsigned char indata, outdata; // then use &indata and &outdata where you need a pointer
```

or

```
unsigned char indata[some_number];
unsigned char outdata[some_number];
```

or you can malloc once before the loop and free once after it.

The double free problem looks like one of the functions you're calling in the loop is calling free. Look carefully at readfile and writefile.

Comment: I wanted to allocate more than 1 byte,i.e., dynamically depending on the number of characters that are in the file. But I'm confused how to allocate memory before knowing the actual no of characters in the file?? And for the option : "or you can malloc once before the loop and free once after it.", how much memory should i allocate before the loop since there can be any number of characters in a file.

Comment: @annunarcist: If you don't know how much memory you need, you can't allocate it. You can decide that it won't ever be more than X and allocate X, but you may as well do that statically. Why does `readfile` need `indata`?

Comment: @annunarcist: You're going to need another function call to find out how much data there is in the file (`see stat(2)`) if you want to allocate space for it.

Comment: is there any possibility that it still gives as error as it is giving me as inside the function : for(i=0;i < no_of_files;i++) {
indata = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));
outdata = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));
numCharacters = readfile(filename, indata); 
/* perform some operation on indata and get outdata(size is same as indata)*/
writefile(filename, outdata);   
    free(indata);
    indata = NULL;
    free(outdata);
    outdata = NULL;}  .When the loop in executing for the 2nd time & malloc is called for indata, it is collecting some garbage value and storing in it.